# paring complex json data using R getting error

Tags: r

### Using R to parse the json data to Read as data frame

```
library(jsonlite)
result <- fromJSON("2018-12-27_Execution.json",flatten=FALSE)
```

getting error like :

> Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
>                                        12:02:45.5385 Info {    "message"
>                        (right here) ------^

My data looks like this....

```
 12:02:45.5385 Info {
      "message": "Mouse and Keyboard execution started",
      "level": "Information",
      "logType": "Default",
      "timeStamp": "2018-12-26T12:02:45.5050962+05:30",
      "fingerprint": "54add266-e135-4cdd-b89c-36bce3e9a089",
      "windowsIdentity": "DESKTOP-D2258GK\\Rahul Arora",
      "machineName": "DESKTOP-D2258GK",
      "processName": "Mouse and Keyboard",
      "processVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "jobId": "07736e9d-b1c3-4529-9bd7-a5255d2eaa98",
      "robotName": "RAHUL ARORA",
      "machineId": 0,
      "fileName": "Main"
    }12:02:50.9663 Info {
      "message": "Mouse and Keyboard execution ended",
      "level": "Information",
      "logType": "Default",
      "timeStamp": "2018-12-26T12:02:50.9663451+05:30",
      "fingerprint": "cc748786-c960-4f46-9b07-b1d13c395a4f",
      "windowsIdentity": "DESKTOP-D2258GK\\Rahul Arora",
      "machineName": "DESKTOP-D2258GK",
      "processName": "Mouse and Keyboard",
      "processVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "jobId": "07736e9d-b1c3-4529-9bd7-a5255d2eaa98",
      "robotName": "RAHUL ARORA",
      "machineId": 0,
      "totalExecutionTimeInSeconds": 5,
      "totalExecutionTime": "00:00:05",
      "fileName": "Main"
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a standard json. JSON keys are supposed to be in strings.  You can try putting your json to this validator https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

somthing issues into androdid cod, i checked json format is ok. 
here is ref link for check json format is valid or not. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/